# How to use imported javascript library constructor in vue.js component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to reuse a javascript library I did some time ago in a vue.js component.

The js library works like this:

1. simple reference on the main script with  tag
2. css loading

The library provides a constructor, so what is needed is a  element with an ID and to init the component in javascript I only need to:

```
var divelement = new pCalendar("#divelement", {
    ... various options
});
```

I'm trying to create a .vue component that is able to do the same (loading js library, init css, init component with the constructor and options), but I can't figure out what is the right way to do it.

This is what I'm working on, but in this situation I get an error because pCalendar is not recognized as constructor.

```
<template>
    <div id="myelement"></div>
</template>
<script>
    import perpetual_calendar from '../../../assets/js/perpetual-calendar/perpetual_calendar.js'
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        myelement: '',
      }
    },
    mounted(){
          var myelement = new pCalendar("#myelement",{
        ... various options
});        
      } ,  

 }
</script>
<style lang="css">
    @import '../../../assets/js/perpetual-calendar/pcalendar_style.css';
</style>
```

**Edit 1** (answer to @Daniyal Lukmanov question):

perpetual_calendar.js looks like this:

```
var pCalendar = function (element, options) {
    this.options = {};
    this.initializeElement(element);
    this.initializeOptions(options || {});
    this._create();
}
...

pCalendar.prototype.initializeElement = function (element) {
    var canCreate = false;
    if (typeof HTMLElement !== "undefined" && element instanceof HTMLElement) {
        this.element = element;
        canCreate = true;
    } else if (typeof element === "string") {
        this.element = document.querySelector(element);
        if (this.element) {
            canCreate = true;
        } else {
            canCreate = false;
        }
    } else {
        canCreate = false;
    }

    if (canCreate === true) {
        if (document.getElementsByName(this.element.id+"_store").length!=0) {
            canCreate = false;
        }    
    }
    return canCreate;
};

and so on ...
```

**Edit 2**: this is the initializeOptions function, that is throwing the TypeError: "this.element is null" error.

```
pCalendar.prototype.initializeOptions = function (options) {
    // begin hardcoded options, don't touch!!!
    this.options['objectId'] = this.element.id;
    this.options['firstMonth'] = null;
       (... various options)
    // end hardcoded options

    for (var key in this.defaultOptions) {
       ( ... loop to load options - default one or defined by user in the constructor)
    }
};
```

Comment: How does `perpetual_calendar.js` look like? And what is `pCalendar` if you import `perpetual_calendar`?

Comment: @DaniyalLukmanov, I've just edidted the question in order to give you more details.

Comment: If you don't export pCalendar you obviously won't be able to use it outside perpetual_calendar.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you `perpetual_calendar.js` file, you need to `export` the `pCalendar` in order to use it. At the bottom of the `perpetual_calendar.js` file, add:

```js
export {
  pCalendar
};
```

Now, you should be able to import and use it like so:

```js
import { pCalendar } from './perpetual_calendar.js';
let calendar = new pCalendar({ /* parameters*/ });
```

**EDIT After adding `initializeElement` method**

There are a few things wrong in the code:

1. It seems that not all code paths of `initializeElement` set the `this.element` variable.
2. `document.querySelector` will not work in vue. You will need to pass the element via the `this.$refs` variable:

```js
<template>
    <div id="myelement" ref="myelement"></div>
</template>
<script>
    import perpetual_calendar from '../../../assets/js/perpetual-calendar/perpetual_calendar.js'
  export default {
    data () {
      return {
        myelement: '',
      }
    },
    mounted(){
          var myelement = new pCalendar(this.$refs["myelement"], { /* various options */ });        
    }

 }
</script>
<style lang="css">
    @import '../../../assets/js/perpetual-calendar/pcalendar_style.css';
</style>
```

Now, you can pass the `element` to your `perpetual_calendar` as directly as an object instead of having to use `document.querySelector`:

```js
pCalendar.prototype.initializeElement = function (element) {
    this.element = element.
    return true;
};
```

Comment: I've tried also this, but it is not working. I've added the pCalendar definition inside the library in the question.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer as I see what the issue is now.

Comment: Ok, it finally makes sense... But I'm getting a TypeError: "this.element is null" in console. In fact, element is null and is not linked anyhow on the <div> element that is delcared in <template>.

Comment: Can you update your post with the new code that is throwing this exception? Or maybe even create a new question so that the context of this one is not lost for other people having this issue.

Comment: Of course, I decided to update this one, as the topic refers to the whole "how to"

Comment: I will need the code for `initializeElement` too, as I suspect that something goes wrong there.

Comment: Updated my answer. In short, it comes down to the `document.querySelector` not being available in vue. What you will have to do is add a `ref` attribute to you HTML element, and access it using the `this.$refs` variable.